# Compiling Graphin for windows

Tags: c++, graphics, linker, antialiasing

I am trying to compile Graphin for windows present here

```
svn checkout http://graphin.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ graphin-read-only
```

But with VS 2005 it fails with

```
1>------ Build started: Project: graphin, Configuration: Release Win32 ------
1>Linking...
1>   Creating library .\../../bin/graphin.lib and object .\../../bin/graphin.exp
1>agg2d.lib(agg2D.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall agg::vcgen_dash::remove_all_dashes(void)" (?remove_all_dashes@vcgen_dash@agg@@QAEXXZ) referenced in function "public: void __thiscall agg::conv_dash<class agg::conv_curve<class agg::path_base<class agg::vertex_block_storage<double,8,256> >,class agg::curve3,class agg::curve4>,struct agg::null_markers>::remove_all_dashes(void)" (?remove_all_dashes@?$conv_dash@V?$conv_curve@V?$path_base@V?$vertex_block_storage@N$07$0BAA@@agg@@@agg@@Vcurve3@2@Vcurve4@2@@agg@@Unull_markers@2@@agg@@QAEXXZ)
1>agg2d.lib(agg2D.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall agg::vcgen_dash::add_dash(double,double)" (?add_dash@vcgen_dash@agg@@QAEXNN@Z) referenced in function "public: void __thiscall agg::conv_dash<class agg::conv_curve<class agg::path_base<class agg::vertex_block_storage<double,8,256> >,class agg::curve3,class agg::curve4>,struct agg::null_markers>::add_dash(double,double)" (?add_dash@?$conv_dash@V?$conv_curve@V?$path_base@V?$vertex_block_storage@N$07$0BAA@@agg@@@agg@@Vcurve3@2@Vcurve4@2@@agg@@Unull_markers@2@@agg@@QAEXNN@Z)
1>agg2d.lib(agg2D.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall agg::vcgen_dash::dash_start(double)" (?dash_start@vcgen_dash@agg@@QAEXN@Z) referenced in function "public: void __thiscall agg::conv_dash<class agg::conv_curve<class agg::path_base<class agg::vertex_block_storage<double,8,256> >,class agg::curve3,class agg::curve4>,struct agg::null_markers>::dash_start(double)" (?dash_start@?$conv_dash@V?$conv_curve@V?$path_base@V?$vertex_block_storage@N$07$0BAA@@agg@@@agg@@Vcurve3@2@Vcurve4@2@@agg@@Unull_markers@2@@agg@@QAEXN@Z)
1>agg2d.lib(agg2D.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: unsigned int __thiscall agg::vcgen_dash::vertex(double *,double *)" (?vertex@vcgen_dash@agg@@QAEIPAN0@Z) referenced in function "public: unsigned int __thiscall agg::conv_adaptor_vcgen<class agg::conv_curve<class agg::path_base<class agg::vertex_block_storage<double,8,256> >,class agg::curve3,class agg::curve4>,class agg::vcgen_dash,struct agg::null_markers>::vertex(double *,double *)" (?vertex@?$conv_adaptor_vcgen@V?$conv_curve@V?$path_base@V?$vertex_block_storage@N$07$0BAA@@agg@@@agg@@Vcurve3@2@Vcurve4@2@@agg@@Vvcgen_dash@2@Unull_markers@2@@agg@@QAEIPAN0@Z)
1>agg2d.lib(agg2D.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall agg::vcgen_dash::rewind(unsigned int)" (?rewind@vcgen_dash@agg@@QAEXI@Z) referenced in function "public: unsigned int __thiscall agg::conv_adaptor_vcgen<class agg::conv_curve<class agg::path_base<class agg::vertex_block_storage<double,8,256> >,class agg::curve3,class agg::curve4>,class agg::vcgen_dash,struct agg::null_markers>::vertex(double *,double *)" (?vertex@?$conv_adaptor_vcgen@V?$conv_curve@V?$path_base@V?$vertex_block_storage@N$07$0BAA@@agg@@@agg@@Vcurve3@2@Vcurve4@2@@agg@@Vvcgen_dash@2@Unull_markers@2@@agg@@QAEIPAN0@Z)
1>agg2d.lib(agg2D.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall agg::vcgen_dash::add_vertex(double,double,unsigned int)" (?add_vertex@vcgen_dash@agg@@QAEXNNI@Z) referenced in function "public: unsigned int __thiscall agg::conv_adaptor_vcgen<class agg::conv_curve<class agg::path_base<class agg::vertex_block_storage<double,8,256> >,class agg::curve3,class agg::curve4>,class agg::vcgen_dash,struct agg::null_markers>::vertex(double *,double *)" (?vertex@?$conv_adaptor_vcgen@V?$conv_curve@V?$path_base@V?$vertex_block_storage@N$07$0BAA@@agg@@@agg@@Vcurve3@2@Vcurve4@2@@agg@@Vvcgen_dash@2@Unull_markers@2@@agg@@QAEIPAN0@Z)
1>agg2d.lib(agg2D.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall agg::vcgen_dash::remove_all(void)" (?remove_all@vcgen_dash@agg@@QAEXXZ) referenced in function "public: unsigned int __thiscall agg::conv_adaptor_vcgen<class agg::conv_curve<class agg::path_base<class agg::vertex_block_storage<double,8,256> >,class agg::curve3,class agg::curve4>,class agg::vcgen_dash,struct agg::null_markers>::vertex(double *,double *)" (?vertex@?$conv_adaptor_vcgen@V?$conv_curve@V?$path_base@V?$vertex_block_storage@N$07$0BAA@@agg@@@agg@@Vcurve3@2@Vcurve4@2@@agg@@Vvcgen_dash@2@Unull_markers@2@@agg@@QAEIPAN0@Z)
1>agg2d.lib(agg2D.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall agg::vcgen_dash::vcgen_dash(void)" (??0vcgen_dash@agg@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function "public: __thiscall agg::conv_adaptor_vcgen<class agg::conv_curve<class agg::path_base<class agg::vertex_block_storage<double,8,256> >,class agg::curve3,class agg::curve4>,class agg::vcgen_dash,struct agg::null_markers>::conv_adaptor_vcgen<class agg::conv_curve<class agg::path_base<class agg::vertex_block_storage<double,8,256> >,class agg::curve3,class agg::curve4>,class agg::vcgen_dash,struct agg::null_markers>(class agg::conv_curve<class agg::path_base<class agg::vertex_block_storage<double,8,256> >,class agg::curve3,class agg::curve4> &)" (??0?$conv_adaptor_vcgen@V?$conv_curve@V?$path_base@V?$vertex_block_storage@N$07$0BAA@@agg@@@agg@@Vcurve3@2@Vcurve4@2@@agg@@Vvcgen_dash@2@Unull_markers@2@@agg@@QAE@AAV?$conv_curve@V?$path_base@V?$vertex_block_storage@N$07$0BAA@@agg@@@agg@@Vcurve3@2@Vcurve4@2@@1@@Z)
1>.\../../bin/graphin.dll : fatal error LNK1120: 8 unresolved externals
1>Build log was saved at "file://c:\graphin-read-only\build\release\BuildLog.htm"
1>graphin - 9 error(s), 0 warning(s)
2>------ Build started: Project: win32, Configuration: Release Win32 ------
2>Linking...
2>Embedding manifest...
2>Build log was saved at "file://c:\graphin-read-only\Release\win32\BuildLog.htm"
2>win32 - 0 error(s), 0 warning(s)
========== Build: 1 succeeded, 1 failed, 4 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Kindly help me with it to get rid of it...

Comment: Did you include the `.lib` in your project?

Comment: I dont get error while using it, i get error while compiling their own library...

Comment: Nice one! Then there are other unresolved dependencies!! Do they have a manual where you can find additional dependencies?

Comment: Nope their site does not mention any... https://code.google.com/p/graphin/ this is their link...

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the library depends on another library called "`anti-grain-geometry`". You will probably need to acquire it, and gain a `.lib`-file from it.

[AGG](http://agg.sourceforge.net/) can be found there.

Comment: Thanks for response but this project is not dependent on matplotlib the undefine ref are from AGG (anti-grain library) which this is using...

Comment: But i dont from where i can get ans of these undefine ref, i am sure it is not using matplotlib asi investigated its dependecies...